# Most efficient way to manage formatted strings for constantly updated UIlabels in Xcode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a UILabel in an interactive calculator application that is continually being refreshed with a newly formatted message as the user changes a UISlider value. My question is what is the most efficient way to manage the strings:

```
NSString *data = [[NSString *alloc] initWithFormat:@"Value A: %0.1f, Value B: %0.1f, valueA,valueB];
myUILabel.text = data;
[data release];
```

or

```
[myMutableString setString:@""];
[myMutableString appendFormat:@"Value A: %0.1f, Value B: %0.1f, valueA,valueB];
myUILabel.text = myMutableString;
```

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a single, non-mutable string (your first example) is going to be more efficient than creating and then modifying a mutable string.

However the real answer is that it doesn't matter. The amount of time is negligible in user interaction terms, and any temporary objects created as a side effect will be freed on every pass through the event loop anyway, so worrying about this at all is premature optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the comments
The mutable string would be a class instance variable created only once. Perhaps as you say I am worrying too much. I blame Instruments :- I ran my code through it and saw lots of allocations, so thought re-using the variables might be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

As the string is there to be read by the user and so has to remain visible for a time I doubt that the speed of the format matters as it will take much less time than it takes for a user to read the value.

Comment: I was thinking of efficiency from a memory management point of view